# Best way to use a unit test to read and then delete xml files

Tags: unit-testing, tomcat, grails

I created a unit test in which I dynamically create and then parse an xml. When I'm finished with the file I delete it. I'm storing the file momentarily in a created resource folder within my project,but I want to know will this still pass if I deploy to a tomcat server. I'm using getRealPath () right now and it works. I in no way need these files later on which is why I'm deleting them.

I've read the getRealPath () isn't portable and shouldn't really be used but that's why I'm asking for my purpose would it be ok?

I can't post code because I'm at work but I'll try to explain somewhat:

I use ServletContextHolder.servletcontext.getRealPath () and add resources/testfiles to the end..this takes me to my project path (project/out/test/resources/testfiles)

I create an xml file using stringwriter,filewriter,markupbuilder..

I save this file, read it and delete it after the test..it works on windows but I need to know if it'll work on tomcat if it is deployed and the unit tests run automatically..will it be able to do all this..

Apologies for poor format my phone isn't the best way to write this

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve, precisely, and post the code you used to do it. Then we'll comment. The explanation should tell where the XML files come from, where they're located, etc.

Comment: You're asking us if some unknown code will fulfill unknown requirements. We can't help. What you're doing in the unit tests is irrelevant to your question. If your company refuses that you post code, then it should do your support.

Comment: My unit test is the only thing using getRealPath,it's just testing if the xml parser works as expected..all I am asking is will this test still pass if I move it to a tomcat server..I heard that getRealPath isn't something that should be used because the files are deleted but seeing how I just create them and then delete them would it really matter

Comment: If your unit test is using getRealPath(), and thus runs inside a deployed web application, it's not a unit test. Unit tests are not supposed to run in a web application.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to not use files at all. But it really depends on what class your XML parser uses for its input. For example, if the parser accepts an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), you can use a [StringBufferInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html) to build your XML content. The parser would then be able to use that stream as if it were a file. OOP interfaces are awesome like that :)